# Ordered data structure with fixed size and pop/push simultaneous operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

What python data structure do you recommend with this requirements:

- Fixed size defined at init
- Ordered data
- Adding a data at the beginning of the structure remove the data at it's end (as a queue structure)
- Adding the data at the beginning return the data at it's end
- Any data could be accessible, but not removed
- Structure can be cleaned

I looked structure like lists but it does not provide me what I want. dequeue seems great but I don't specifically need to add or remove element at both sides.

I would like something like that:

```py
last_object = my_struct.add(new_first_object)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `deque` seems fine, just because you _can_ add elements at both ends doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: when you say "Adding the data at the beginning return the data at it's end", if the queue is full, it means return the one that was just popped out?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) initialized with `maxlen` is exactly what you need, it can do the operations you need in `O(1)`, and the "removing at the end" is taken care of:

> If maxlen is not specified or is None, deques may grow to an arbitrary length. Otherwise, the deque is bounded to the specified maximum length. Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added, a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.

just use `.append` and nothing else.

as per the docs, it also supports "peeking" at [0] or [-1] in O(1) (for the "Adding the data at the beginning return the data at it's end" requirement)

If you really don't want any other method to exist on your class (e.g. so IDEs don't auto-complete stuff other than your `add`) you can wrap `deque` in your own custom class the has just an `add` method that calls the `deque`'s `append`.

example:

```py
from collections import deque

class MyCollection:
    def __init__(self, maxlen):
        self.d = deque(maxlen=maxlen)

    def add(self, new_first_object):
        result = None if len(self.d)==0 else self.d[0]
        self.d.append(new_first_object)
        return result

my_struct = MyCollection(3)
my_struct.add(1)
my_struct.add(2)
my_struct.add(3) # my_struct is now full
print(my_struct.add(4))
print(my_struct.add(5))
print(my_struct.add(6))
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: If I correctly get this line `result = None if len(self.d)==0 else self.d[0]` the last element is at index 0 !?

Comment: you can use `.appendleft` and then it will be in index `[-1]`... "last" is relative :)